# Numerical integrate a matrix valued function whose arguments limited to be numerical

Tags: numerical-integration, numerics

I'm encountering non-numerical errors when using NIntegrate to integrate a matrix-valued function whose arguments are restricted to numerical values. Setting `SymbolicProcessing -> False` doesn't seem to resolve the issue. Here's a demonstration function (f3) along with comparison functions (f1 and f2) for reference.

```
f1[x_] := {Integrate[y, {y, 0, x}], x + 1};
f2[x_] := {NIntegrate[y, {y, 0, x}], x + 1};
f3[x_?NumericQ] := {NIntegrate[y, {y, 0, x}], x + 1};
NIntegrate[f1[xx], {xx, 1.0, 2.3}, 
 Method -> {Automatic, "SymbolicProcessing" -> False}]
NIntegrate[f2[xx], {xx, 1.0, 2.3}, 
 Method -> {Automatic, "SymbolicProcessing" -> False}]
NIntegrate[f3[xx], {xx, 1.0, 2.3}, 
 Method -> {Automatic, "SymbolicProcessing" -> False}]
```

Comment: why are you calling `NIntegrate` passing it another `NIntegrate`? You basically wrote `NIntegrate[NIntegrate[y,{y,0,x}],{x,1.0,2.3}]`

Comment: This is just a demonstration of this problem, NIntegrate in f3 was just used to constraint f3 to only accept numerical arguments, so it can be replaced by any numerical function.@Nasser